# ALSA Error: ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1713:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, microphone, alsa, input

Hey there dear community,

I have been struggling with getting a Raspberry 3b+ and microphone setup to run for a few days now, interestingly getting the same error on both projects simultaneously even though they run on different operating systems.
I tried both with a seeed respeaker 6mic array and with a Logitech USB-Mic to record via aplay/arecord and get the above error

ALSA Error: ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1713:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
Playback open error: -2, No such file or directory

even though I've got all the drivers, specified the correct card and device in the asound.conf, checked if alsa-utils are installed...

Any idea where I could look? 
xx de

Comment: You "specified the correct card"? What is the correct card? How do you know that?

Comment: I looked up via aplay -l and arecord -l what card and device numbers alsa assigned the speakers and microphone, and used those in my asound.conf, like so:

pcm.!default { type asym playback.pcm 
    { type plug slave.pcm "hw:0" } 
    capture.pcm { type plug slave.pcm "hw:1" } 
}

which some users on the forums said solved this problem for them

Comment: Please show the output of `aplay -l`.